# Sharing Classes in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

This [article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/module-pattern-in-javascript-and-coffeescript) explains how to implement the "Module Pattern" in CoffeeScript.

How can I share a CoffeeScript `class` between javascript files?

For example:

```
class A 
  constructor: (@x) ->
```

How can I share `A` between two CoffeeScript files?

Comment: How are you transpiling / running your coffeescript? Webpack / Requirejs/ node?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.A = class A 
  constructor: (@x) ->
```

or:

```
class window.A
  constructor: (@x) ->
```

Both of which will compile to:

```
(function() {
  var A;

  window.A = A = (function() {
    function A(x) {
      this.x = x;
    }

    return A;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

You can also use `@A` instead if `window.A` in both places if you prefer, since `this` refers to `window` outside any function.

Answer (score 0):

Read about UMD. You can implement UMD header in this way:

```
((root, factory) ->
  ### istanbul ignore next ###
  switch
    when typeof define is 'function' and define.amd
      define ['underscore', 'backbone-forms'], factory
    when typeof exports is 'object'
      factory require('underscore'), require('backbone-forms')
    else
      factory root._, root.Backbone.Form
  return
) @, (_, Form) ->
  class A 
    constructor: (@x) ->
```

`underscore` and `backbone-forms` are a example dependencies.